# updateDatabase does not support the driver attribute on liquibase version 4.17.2

Tags: jenkins, ant, liquibase

We are using Liquibase for database updation in deployment pipeline with Ant script. Existing version of liquibase-core jar file is 3.8.3 and i want to upgrade to 4.17.2. I put updated version into C:\Installations\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin\apache-ant-1.9.4\lib folder and replace the version in liquibase-build.xml file which is in jenkins_files/ant_script/liquibase-build.xml file.
After the above upgrade i run the process then it is giving below error:

```
update-database:

BUILD FAILED
D:\repos\testdomainhorzion1_diageotest_com7470\scripts\rollout\liquibase-build.xml:34: updateDatabase doesn’t support the “driver” attribute"

Total time: 0 seconds
Build step ‘Conditional steps (multiple)’ marked build as failure
Performing Post build task…
Could not match :liquibase.exception : False
Could not match :Build step ‘Execute Windows batch command’ marked build as failure : False
Could not match :UnexpectedLiquibaseException : False
Logical operation result is FALSE
```

How to solve this issue as liquibase doesnot support updateDatabase property?

We are trying to update Liquibase build script but didn't get success yet. If UpdateDatabase property is working with Liquibase 3.8.3 then why is not working with Liquibase 4.17.2

Answer (score 0):

@abhishek! There were some changes when upgrading from version 3.x.x to version 4.x.x. We have a guide on the forum for resolving the most common issues when [Upgrading from Liquibase 3.x to 4.x](https://forum.liquibase.org/t/upgrading-from-liquibase-3-x-to-4-x/6246).

> When you reference a changelog file like /path/to/changelog.xml or
> path/to/changelog.xmlorchangelog.xml`, Liquibase has always looked for
> those by searching through all the directories and files in your
> “classpath”. It has never mattered whether you have a / at the beginning
> of your filename or not, the path you give is always looked for inside the
> entries in your classpath.

Additional information is provided in the link above.

Comment: Please see my code and let me know where i have to change

Comment: Thanks for your response but we are getting updateDatase attribute is not executing.